# pd.get_dummies() for DataFrames with multi-index columns

Tags: python, pandas

Using [`get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html), it is possible to create one-hot encoded dummy variables for categorical data. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'a'], 
                   'B': ['b', 'a', 'c']})
print(pd.get_dummies(df))

#    A_a  A_b  B_a  B_b  B_c
# 0    1    0    0    1    0
# 1    0    1    1    0    0
# 2    1    0    0    0    1
```

So far, so good. But how can I use `get_dummies()` in combination with multi-index columns? The default behavior is not very practical: The multi-index tuple is converted into a string and the same suffix mechanism applies as with the simple-index columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({('i','A'): ['a', 'b', 'a'], 
                   ('ii','B'): ['b', 'a', 'c']})
ret = pd.get_dummies(df)
print(ret)
print(type(ret.columns[0]))

#    ('i','A')_a  ('i','A')_b  ('ii','B')_a  ('ii','B')_b  ('ii','B')_c
# 0            1            0             0             1             0
# 1            0            1             1             0             0
# 2            1            0             0             0             1
#
# str
```

What I would like to get, however, is that the dummies create a new column level:

```
ret = pd.get_dummies(df, ???)
print(ret)
print(type(ret.columns[0]))

#    i    ii
#    A     B
#    a  b  a  b  c
# 0  1  0  0  1  0
# 1  0  1  1  0  0
# 2  1  0  0  0  1
#
# tuple
#

# Note that the ret would be equivalent to the following:
#   ('i','A','a') ('i','A','b') ('ii','B','a') ('ii','B','b') ('ii','B','c')
# 0            1             0              0              1              0
# 1            0             1              1              0              0
# 2            1             0              0              0              1
```

How could this be achieved?

**Update**: I placed a feature request for better support of multi-index data-frames in `get_dummies`: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/26560

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the column names and rename them:

```
import ast
def parse_dummy(x):
    parts = x.split('_')
    return ast.literal_eval(parts[0]) + (parts[1],)

ret.columns = pd.Series(ret.columns).apply(parse_dummy)
#   (i, A, a)  (i, A, b)  (ii, B, a)  (ii, B, b)  (ii, B, c)
#0          1          0           0           1           0
#1          0          1           1           0           0
#2          1          0           0           0           1
```

Note that this DataFrame is not the same as a DataFrame with three-level multiindex column names.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need, but in a more complex DataFrame, with a multi index as row index and numerical columns which shall not be converted to dummy. So my case required to scan through the columns, expand to dummy only the columns of `dtype='object'`, and build a new column index as a concatenation of the name of the column with the dummy variable and the value of the dummy variable itself. This because I didn't want to add a new column index level.

Here is the code
first build a dataframe in the format I need

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_size = 3
objects = ['obj1','obj2']
attributes = ['a1','a2','a3']
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([objects, attributes], names=['objects', 'attributes'])
lab1 = ['car','truck','van']
lab2 = ['bay','zoe','ros','lol']
time = np.arange(df_size)
node = ['n1','n2']
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([time, node], names=['time', 'node'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10,size=(len(idx),len(cols))),columns=cols,index=idx)
c1 = map(lambda i:lab1[i],np.random.randint(len(lab1),size=len(idx)))
c2 = map(lambda i:lab2[i],np.random.randint(len(lab2),size=len(idx)))
df[('obj1','a3')]=list(c1)
df[('obj2','a2')]=list(c2)
print(df)
```

```
objects    obj1           obj2        
attributes   a1 a2     a3   a1   a2 a3
time node                             
0    n1       6  5  truck    3  ros  3
     n2       5  6    car    9  lol  7
1    n1       0  8  truck    7  zoe  8
     n2       4  3  truck    8  bay  3
2    n1       5  8    van    0  bay  0
     n2       4  8    car    5  lol  4
```

And here is the code to dummify only the object columns

```
for t in [df.columns[i] for i,dt in enumerate(df.dtypes) if dt=='object']:
    dummy_block = pd.get_dummies( df[t] )
    dummy_block.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[t[0]],[f'{t[1]}_{c}' for c in dummy_block.columns]],
                                                     names=df.columns.names)
    df = pd.concat([df.drop(t,axis=1),dummy_block],axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)

print(df)
```

```
objects    obj1                           obj2                               
attributes   a1 a2 a3_car a3_truck a3_van   a1 a2_bay a2_lol a2_ros a2_zoe a3
time node                                                                    
0    n1       6  5      0        1      0    3      0      0      1      0  3
     n2       5  6      1        0      0    9      0      1      0      0  7
1    n1       0  8      0        1      0    7      0      0      0      1  8
     n2       4  3      0        1      0    8      1      0      0      0  3
2    n1       5  8      0        0      1    0      1      0      0      0  0
     n2       4  8      1        0      0    5      0      1      0      0  4
```

It can be easily changed to answer to original use case, adding one more row to the columns multi index.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({('i','A'): ['a', 'b', 'a'], 
                   ('ii','B'): ['b', 'a', 'c']})
print(df)
```

```
i ii
   A  B
0  a  b
1  b  a
2  a  c
```

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([t+('',) for t in df.columns])
for t in [df.columns[i] for i,dt in enumerate(df.dtypes) if dt=='object']:
    dummy_block = pd.get_dummies( df[t] )
    dummy_block.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[t[0]],[t[1]],[c for c in dummy_block.columns]],
                                                     names=df.columns.names)
    df = pd.concat([df.drop(t,axis=1),dummy_block],axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
print(df)
```

```
   i    ii      
   A     B      
   a  b  a  b  c
0  1  0  0  1  0
1  0  1  1  0  0
2  1  0  0  0  1
```

note that it still works if there are numerical columns - it just adds an empty additional level to them in the columns index as well.